# What is "wdm" when executing ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Whenever I use `ng serve` in my Angular projects, I get console output like the following:

```
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I have searched for an explanation as to what `wdm` actually is, but found nothing so far. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You've tagged this with the [wdm] tag, which is specifically for Windows Device Model, which is unlikely to be used in Angular. Please only use tags that you know are relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your feedback, I removed the rogue tag.

Comment: should not have been down voted. its a sensible question from windows platform view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for `webpack-dev-middleware`, meaning that you're getting logs from this [middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware).

They use shortcut `wdm`, because `webpack-dev-middleware` have long name in console and it looks ugly.